# how do i make the canvas perfectly fit to the window size in p5

Tags: window, p5.js, screen-size, p5.play

i want to make the p5 canvas fit perfectly to the window size, but whenever I use windowWidth and windowHeight , the canvas seems to be bigger:

[image: The canvas stretches outside]

is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 14):

You need to turn off margin and padding for the `<html>` and `<body>` tags with CSS (this removes the white border around the canvas), and turn off the vertical scrollbar.

Also, if someone changes the size of the window, you'll want to handle that, which is done easily with the [`windowResized` event](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowResized).

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i made margin and padding 0 still canvas was looking little bigger but i tried this

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

and it worked.
the scrollbars were reducing size of viewport so hiding them make canvas fit perfectly.